# Two-Dimensional Array Rectangle in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2013, rectangles

I need to create a new rectangle using two dimensional arrays in C#.

I created an image called brick_fw and imported it into the IDE for the game I'm creating.

Here's the code I have (which is in it's own class named Brick):

```
brickLength = 60;
brickHeight = 20;
int[,] brickLocation = { { 0, 0 }, { 62, 0 }, { 123, 0 }, { 184, 0 }, { 245, 0 }, { 306, 0 }, { 367, 0 } };
bool[] brickLive = { true, true, true, true, true, true, true };

brickImage = Breakout.Properties.Resources.brick_fw;
brickRec = new Rectangle(x, y, brickLength, brickHeight);
```

The problem I have here is;
`brickRec` can only use the integer values of x and y and only accepts this way of representing a new rectangle (meaning if I remove the x and y from the brackets and replace it with `brickLocation` then the compiler will moan).

As it stands, the compiler will only draw a single brick into the program because it's not taking into account the two dimensional array. 
Is there a way to represent this `brickLocation` within the Rectangle function?

EDIT:

```
public Brick()
{
    brickLength = 60;
    brickHeight = 20;
    int[,] brickLocation = { { 0, 0 }, { 62, 0 }, { 123, 0 }, { 184, 0 }, { 245, 0 }, { 306, 0 }, { 367, 0 } };
    bool[] brickLive = { true, true, true, true, true, true, true };

    brickImage = Breakout.Properties.Resources.brick_fw;

    for (int i = 0; i < brickLocation.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        brickRec = new Rectangle(brickLocation[i, 0], brickLocation[i, 1], brickLength, brickHeight);

    }
}


public void drawBrick(Graphics paper)
{
    paper.DrawImage(brickImage, brickRec);
}
```

Comment: `brickLocation[1,0], brickLocation[1,1]` will give you `62` for `x` and `0` for `y`. If that doesn't do what you want, you'll need to explain further. Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry. I'll try and explain it a little better. Basically, I want to use the coordinates you see in `brickLocation` for my declaration of `brickRec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Rectangle` value can only represent a single rectangle, so if you want multiple rectangles you would loop through one dimension of the array and create a rectangle for each pair of values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < brickLocation.GetLength(0); i++) {
  brickRec = new Rectangle(brickLocation[i, 0], brickLocation[i, 1], brickLength, brickHeight);
  // draw the rectangle
}
```

#### Edit:

To do the drawing of the rectangles separate from the creation of the rectangles, you would put them in an array of rectangles:

```
private Rectangle[] brickRec;

public Brick()
{
    brickLength = 60;
    brickHeight = 20;
    int[,] brickLocation = { { 0, 0 }, { 62, 0 }, { 123, 0 }, { 184, 0 }, { 245, 0 }, { 306, 0 }, { 367, 0 } };
    bool[] brickLive = { true, true, true, true, true, true, true };

    brickImage = Breakout.Properties.Resources.brick_fw;

    brickRec = new Rectangle[brickLocation.GetLength(0)];
    for (int i = 0; i < brickLocation.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        brickRec[i] = new Rectangle(brickLocation[i, 0], brickLocation[i, 1], brickLength, brickHeight);
    }
}


public void drawBrick(Graphics paper)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < brickRec.Length; i++) {
        paper.DrawImage(brickImage, brickRec[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I'm struggling a bit with the code however in order to make it fit into what I'm doing. Here's what I've got so far: (see edit of the question)

Comment: How does one implement the draw function into the `for` loop? If I paste the `drawBrick` code straight into the for loop, the compiler will moan that there is no such thing as `paper`

Comment: @BorisSmith: To do the drawing separate from the creation of the rectangles, you would use an array to store the rectangles. I added code above.